# difference of zip iterator and list

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a list called 'A' also have an iterator called 'B', 'B' is the iterator of 'A'.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

B = iter(A)
```

The output of `zip(A,A,A)` is

```
[(0, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (3, 3, 3),
 (4, 4, 4),
 (5, 5, 5),
 (6, 6, 6),
 (7, 7, 7),
 (8, 8, 8)]
```

The output of `zip(B, B, B)` is

```
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
```

Is anybody can explain the difference

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. How does `zip` work? it creates iterators for each zipped element and goes through them.

When you pass `zip(A,A,A)`, it creates 3 iterators, each will start from `A[0]`.

When you pass `zip(B,B,B)`, you already have an iterator. To create first element of resulting sequence, it calls `B.__iter__()` 3 times. So you get `0,1,2`. For second element it again calls `B.__iter()` 3 times, thus getting `3,4,5` and so forth.

Comment: Actually, `zip` does not create iterators for each zipped element.